# Can't get JSON from php script but can get it from file.json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, typescript

This is what my testing php script is doing:

```
$json = array (
    "age" => 5,
    "bob" => "Lee",
);  
$json = json_encode($json);

echo $json;
```

It prints out the json fine as when I output its content into a file.json and read it from there, the ajax will pick it up.

Ajax part:

```
searchJson(): any 
{   
    let items: any = []; 
    $.getJSON('app/php/search.php', 
        function(data)
        {   
            $.each(data, function (key, val)
            {   
                console.log(key + " : " + val);
                items.push(`${key} : ${val}`);
            }); 
        }); 
    return items;
}
```

Changing 'app/php/search.php' to 'file.json' will return in a non-empty return, whereas now it returns nothing.

Comment: Where is the part where you try to get `file.json`?

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` to view your `response` or the network response of your ajax request

Comment: @Nytrix Substitute 'app/php/search.php' for 'app/php/file.json' and it works

Comment: 'app/php/file.json' is not related with your code. Please tell me what console is showing?

Comment: I think that when I call the `.php` file it's returning the actual contents rather than it being processed by php. Because if I use $.ajax, the console.log returns me all the $ signs and comments

Comment: your returning a data came from a asynchronous function which the items will be return as empty before filling it. better pass a callback for that. but anyway when you `console.log(data);` what are you seeing?

Comment: Ah, I found out the reason. I'm using Angular2 and it doesn't return a proper result when I'm inside their suggested address (10.x.x.x:port), but it returns it correctly when I'm at the actual address www.something.com. It's probably just an Angular2 issue. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: ok................

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was related to running from Angular 2's given address of 10.x.x.x:port. When it's run from www.something.com it will show up correctly.